# How do I write a query for a json in logs insights?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have a simple message in the form of json like below in one of the log group. The query that I use is `{$.level = "INFO"}` This doesn't bring up any result. What could be the problem? Can somebody help please.

```
{
    "level": "INFO",
    "location": "lambda_handler:31",
    "message": {
        "msg": "abc",
        "event": {
            "Records": [
                {
                   .
                   .
                   .
                 }]
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now CloudWatch Log Insights allows to filter based on json fields.
The sintax is as following:

Filter based on field 'level'

```
filter level = 'INFO'
| display level, @message
```

[image]

---

Filter based on nested fields

```
filter message.msg != '123'
| display message.msg, @message
```

[image]

Documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_AnalyzeLogData-discoverable-fields.html#CWL_AnalyzeLogData-discoverable-JSON-logs